# iOS: NSDate compare dates for seconds

Tags: datetime, ios8, nsdate

I need to compare two dates to see if they are within 10 seconds.

```
NSTimeInterval diff = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```

Is the statement above the least expensive way to accomplish this?